# Unable to generate countif with multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets

I'm a little bit stuck at the moment. I have the following formula that works well, but I need to alter it to also check that column AZ includes "Phone".

=COUNTIFS('Results'!B:B, "person", 'Results'!A:A, ">="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),7,1), 'Results'!A:A, "<="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),7,31))

I've tried adding onto that foruma, using filters and many differnt IF functions but have bit a brick wall. Would appricate any help

Comment: So is it not working if you added the additional condition `Results!AZ:AZ, "Phone"` inside your current *countifs()* formula?!

Comment: yes, it does not work, I get back "Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size."

Answer (score 1):

> I need to alter it to also check that column AZ includes "Phone".

Try this out:

```
=COUNTIFS(Results!B:B, "person", Results!A:A, ">="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),7,1), Results!A:A, "<="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),7,31),Results!AZ:AZ,"Phone")
```

Comment: Tried that one, but it returns "Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size."

Comment: this error occurs when not all the ranges in criteria_range have the same size. In the formula I provided they all have the same size so you're very likely using a different formula. Please copy and paste here the formula you're using or consider sharing a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)